# Requesting the most recent version of an entity in CRM

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm updating an entity using the [Organization Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328198(v=crm.5).aspx):

```
    _organizationService.Update(contact);
```

I then would like to immediately query CRM for the latest version of that record by issuing something like:

```
_xrmServiceContext.ContactSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == contactGuid);
```

I'm noticing that the _xrmServiceContext is returning old data, unless I do a Thread.Sleep(1000) before requesting the updated data.

**Is there a way to "wait" until the data is updated?**

I'm looking at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863604(v=crm.5).aspx) as a possible solution; however, I am not sure how I would change my implementation to match this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XrmServiceContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695819(v=crm.7).aspx) takes in organization service as a parameter which is cached.

Use clear changes `_xrmServiceContext.ClearChanges();`

Or alternatively you could new up another [XrmServiceContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695819(v=crm.7).aspx) object by passing a newed up organizationservice.

```
var uncachedOrganizationService = new OrganizationService("Xrm");
var uncachedXrmServiceContext = new XrmServiceContext(uncachedOrganizationService);
uncachedXrmServiceContext.ContactSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == contactGuid);
```

Comment: before executing clear changes should we be doing savechanges?

Comment: If you have any pending entity changes, yes. Calling clear changes will untrack any entity added to track changea.